# Add password field when create customer from admin panel

Tags: magento2, customer-account, password, ui-form, create-account

I disabled the customer register from the frontend and I want only to create customers from backend.
when I create customer in (Customers -> All Customers -> Add New Customer) I want to specify the password for the customer, I found a free module from kiwicommerce called [Customer Password](https://github.com/kiwicommerce/magento2-customer-password), but it only work in edit customer.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the custom customer attributes programmatically as the Password and Confirm Password fields so please follow this referral link.

https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/magento-2-add-customer-attribute-programmatically.html

or

https://www.truecodex.com/course/magento-2/how-to-add-custom-field-in-magento-2-registration-form

Comment: I saw this solution before but its for a custom attribute, I want to add password in the create customer form in backend only, if you do this there will be:
1- Duplicate data in database.
2- 2 more passwords field in registration page.
3- Need to handle the registration event by creating observer and handle the logic, that's why I asked the question.
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this functionality easily by installing this extension [click here](https://marketplace.magento.com/kiwicommerce-module-customer-password.html)

Hope this will help you.

Happy Coding

Comment: I already mentioned this extension in the question, I already had this module installed, but it only shows in the edit user page, I want to extend it's functionality to be shown in the add customer page in backend.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit;

use Magento\Customer\Controller\RegistryConstants;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Layout\Tabs\TabInterface;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form\Generic;
/**
 * Customer account form block
 */
class Tabs extends Generic implements TabInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store
     */
    protected $_systemStore;
    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\FormFactory $formFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\System\Store $systemStore,

        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->_systemStore = $systemStore;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function getCustomerId()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry(RegistryConstants::CURRENT_CUSTOMER_ID);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getTabLabel()
    {
        return __('Demo Tab');
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Phrase
     */
    public function getTabTitle()
    {
        return __('Demo Tab');
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function canShowTab()
    {
        if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isHidden()
    {
        if ($this->getCustomerId()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Tab class getter
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabClass()
    {
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * Return URL link to Tab content
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getTabUrl()
    {
        return '';
    }

    /**
     * Tab should be loaded trough Ajax call
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isAjaxLoaded()
    {
        return false;
    }
    public function initForm()
    {
        if (!$this->canShowTab()) {
            return $this;
        }
        /**@var \Magento\Framework\Data\Form $form */
        $form = $this->_formFactory->create();
        $form->setHtmlIdPrefix('myform_');

        $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('base_fieldset', ['legend' => __('Fields Information')]);

        $fieldset->addField(
            'demo_field',
            'text',
            [
                'name' => 'demo_field',
                'data-form-part' => $this->getData('target_form'),
                'label' => __('Demo Field in Customer Section'),
                'title' => __('Demo Field in Customer Section')
            ]
        );
        $this->setForm($form);
        return $this;
    }
    /**
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        if ($this->canShowTab()) {
            $this->initForm();
            return parent::_toHtml();
        } else {
            return '';
        }
    }
}
```

After that, you can able to get this field

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request */
$request = $this->getRequest();
$originalRequestData = $request->getPostValue();
echo $originalRequestData['demo_field'];
```

Create Plugin for getting data during save.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save">
        <plugin name="sr_customer_save" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Plugin\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

```
class Save
{
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index\Save $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        $demoField = $subject->getRequest()->getParam('demo_field');
        error_log($demoField);
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you. Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand these blocks of code, I tried to understand it but I trying to understand where to put these codes.
1- Create a block file Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit in my custom module.
2- The Second block of code didn't understand it at all, all I got that it's an interface.
3- The Third is for creating a plugin, as I think it could be done with an observer better as done in the module.
4- The fourth code is overriding the save action in the index controller.
That's not what I need, I need to add password filed when create customer from backend.
Thanks for your time and help :)

Answer (score 0):

**you can reset Password from customer edit form instead of customer create form.**

-> VENDOR/MODULE/view/adminhtml/layout/customer_index_edit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="admin-2columns-left"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="customer_edit_tab_view">
            <block class="VENDOR\MODULE\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit\Tab\View\SetPassword" name="update-customer-password" after="customer_form" template="VENDOR_MODULE::update_password.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

-> VENDOR/MODULE/view/adminhtml/templates/update_password.phtml

```
<div class="admin__scope-old">
    <div class="fieldset-wrapper customer-set-password">
        <div class="fieldset-wrapper-title">
            <span class="title"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Set customer password')) ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="fieldset-wrapper-content">
            <form method="POST" action="<?= $block->getUrl('admincustomroute/index/setpassword') ?>">
                <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?= $block->getCustomerId() ?>"/>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="newPassword" class="admin__control-text"/>
                <span onclick="togglePasswordVisibility('newPassword')" class="action-default toggle-password" title="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Toggle password visibility')) ?>">&#128065;</span>
                <button type="submit" class="primary"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Set password')) ?></button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function togglePasswordVisibility(id) {
        var el = document.getElementById(id);
        if (el.type === "password") {
            el.type = "text";
        } else {
            el.type = "password";
        }
    }
</script>
```

-> VENDOR/MODULE/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="admin">
        <route id="admincustomroute" frontName="admincustomroute">
            <module name="VENDOR_MODULE"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

-> VENDOR/MODULE/Block/Adminhtml/Customer/Edit/Tab/View/SetPassword.php

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Block\Adminhtml\Customer\Edit\Tab\View;
use Magento\Customer\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Tab\View\PersonalInfo;
class SetPassword extends PersonalInfo
{
    protected function _toHtml()
    {
        return parent::_toHtml();
    }
}
```

-> VENDOR/MODULE/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/SetPassword.php

```
<?php
namespace VENDOR\MODULE\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;
use Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context;
use Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Model\CustomerRegistry;
use Magento\Framework\Encryption\EncryptorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\InputException;

class SetPassword extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    private $customerRegistry;
    private $customerRepository;
    private $encryptor;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CustomerRegistry $customerRegistry,
        CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository,
        EncryptorInterface $encryptor
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->customerRegistry = $customerRegistry;
        $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
        $this->encryptor = $encryptor;
    }

    protected function _isAllowed()
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $customerId = (int)$this->getRequest()->getPost('id');
        $newPassword = (string)$this->getRequest()->getPost('password');
        try {
            $this->validateNewPassword($newPassword);
            $newPasswordHash = $this->encryptor->getHash($newPassword, true);

            $customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
            $customerSecure = $this->customerRegistry->retrieveSecureData($customer->getId());
            $customerSecure->setPasswordHash($newPasswordHash);
            $this->customerRepository->save($customer);

            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__("You updated this customer's password."));
        }
        catch (InputException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
        }
        catch (\Exception $exception) {
            $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(__('Something went wrong while saving the new password.'));
        }

        return $this->_redirect('customer/index/edit', ['id' => $customerId]);
    }

    protected function validateNewPassword($password)
    {
        if (iconv_strlen($password) <= 0) {
            throw new InputException(__('Please enter a new password.'));
        }
    }
}
```